# htaccess - RewriteCond is met, but RewriteRule doesn't run

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to match both a filename and querystring in my .htaccess file. When using an online testing tool ([this one](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)), it tells me that the conditions are being met, but the following rule doesn't run. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the mod_rewrite part of my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/omialab/omia-linea-erboristica-prodotti-erboristici-per-il-corpo-olio-di-mandorla-argan-jojoba/omia-linea-erboristica-prodotti-erboristici-per-il-corpo-olio-di-mandorla-argan-jojoba.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?cat=1(&.*)pr=4$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?cat=1(&.*)pr=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule https://www.example.com/bagno-seta-mandorla/ [QSD,R=301,L]
```

And here's the URL it's supposed to redirect:

```
http://www.example.com/omialab/omia-linea-erboristica-prodotti-erboristici-per-il-corpo-olio-di-mandorla-argan-jojoba/omia-linea-erboristica-prodotti-erboristici-per-il-corpo-olio-di-mandorla-argan-jojoba.php?cat=1&pr=1
```

Comment: "it tells me that the conditions are being met" - but if you try _those_ directives in _that_ tool it states "This rule was not met."? "the URL it's supposed to redirect" - although the directives you've posted suggest the URL (query string) can be a little more varied - this should be clarified in the question.

Comment: Just to add, that tool is perhaps a little misleading... on a _real_ Apache instance, because the "rule was not met", the preceding conditions would never actually be processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pattern and argument is missing to your `RewriteRule` line.

You also probably can simplify this rule like the following:

```
# if the path is "/omialab/omia-linea-erboristica-prodotti-erboristici-per-il-corpo-olio-di-mandorla-argan-jojoba/omia-linea-erboristica-prodotti-erboristici-per-il-corpo-olio-di-mandorla-argan-jojoba.php"
# and the query string contains a cat parameter valued to "1"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)cat=1(?:&|$)
# and the query string also contains a pr parameter valued to "1" or "4"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)pr=[14](?:&|$)
# then redirect permanently to https://www.example.com/bagno-seta-mandorla/ (without keeping the old query string by the QSD option)
RewriteRule ^omialab/omia-linea-erboristica-prodotti-erboristici-per-il-corpo-olio-di-mandorla-argan-jojoba/omia-linea-erboristica-prodotti-erboristici-per-il-corpo-olio-di-mandorla-argan-jojoba\.php$ https://www.example.com/bagno-seta-mandorla/ [QSD,R=permanent,NC,L]
```

(supposing the `.htaccess` is in `/` directory)